# Data Alerts disabled in Sharepoint 2010 installed in Integrated mode with SSRS

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am using Sharepoint 2010 configured in Integrated mode with SSRS (2012 RC0). Now I am trying to create a Data Alert in my Report. But my Data Alert is always disabled.

I created a Report using Report Builder 3.0 and saved it to a Document Library (using Save As in Report Builder). I am using shared Data Source from the Sharepoint Server.

I am not sure what I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Any pointers to some existing tutorial to create a Data Alert (and pre-requisites to do so) in Sharepoint 2010 Integrated mode would also be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer. The data source should be created with either "Stored Credentials" or "No Credentials". This is a quote from MSDN:

> If the New Data Alert option is grayed, the report data source is
>   configured to use integrated security credentials or prompt for
>   credentials. To make the New Data Alert option available, you must
>   update the data source to use stored credentials or no credentials.

Here is the link for reference:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492251(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492251%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)